# Find the $\arg\min$ over a Frobenius norm

Tags: matrices, partial-differential-equations, estimation

Suppose $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{D}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h} + \mathbf{u}$ is a Gaussian random vector with mean $\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h}$ and variance $\sigma^2\mathbf{I}$.

I try to solve the following equation, but I think there is something wrong...

$$\hat{\mathbf{h}}(\mathbf{r}) = \arg \min_{\mathbf{h}} \left\{ \|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h}\|^2 \right\} \\
= \arg\min_{\mathbf{h}} \left\{\mathbf{r}^h\mathbf{r}+ \left(\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h}\right)^h\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h}-2\left(\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h}\right)^h\mathbf{r}  \right\} $$

let $\mathbf{a} =\mathbf{r}^h\mathbf{r}+ \left(\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h}\right)^h\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h}-2\left(\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h}\right)^h\mathbf{r}$, and sloving

$$\frac{d\mathbf{a}}{d\mathbf{h}} = 0$$

so I got
$$\hat{\mathbf{h}} = ((\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W})^h\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W})^{-1}(\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W})^h\mathbf{r}$$

Comment: Frobenius norm? Looks like the vector $2$-norm to me. Isn't the objective function simply the squared $2$-norm of $\bf u$, which does not depend on $\bf h$? I am confused. Please clarify.

Comment: $\mathbf{u}$ is not depends on $\mathbf{h}$, it is a complex Gaussian vector with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$. The object function is try to find the argmin of $\mathbf{r} - $ $\mathbf{r}$'s mean.

Comment: The question said it is Frobenius norm. If there will have a difference if the norm is vector 2-norm? thanks~

Comment: The Frobenius norm of a vector is its $2$-norm. However, the term "Frobenius norm" is usually used for matrices that are not vectors.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo thanks a lot for your explanation! Then I think the question might be the vector 2-norm...

Comment: I still do not understand the rest of the question. The objective function is the squared $2$-norm of $\bf u$, which is also a random variable. You can take the expected value. However, where is the dependence on $\bf h$?